# Connect using HDBODBC

Tags: powershell, odbc, hana

I've this code to connect to SAP HANA using HDBODBC (which is configured in Windows ODBC data sources):

```
function Get-ODBCBData ($connectstring, $sql) {
    $Conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.ODBCconnection($connectstring)
    $Conn.Open()
    $readcmd = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.ODBCCommand($sql, $Conn)
    $readcmd.CommandTimeout = '300'

    $da = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.ODBCDataAdapter($readcmd)
    $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    [void]$da.Fill($dt)
    $Conn.Close()
    return $dt
}

$hdbSqlCmd = "myquery"
$hdbConnectionString = "Driver={HDBODBC};ServerNode=xxxxxx.xxx.xxx:30015;UID=username;PWD=password;"
Get-ODBCBData $hdbConnectionString $hdbSqlCmd
```

But I get this error:

[image: PowerShell - Error]

Comment: Can you copy/paste your error in your question in stead of the image please ?

Comment: Looks like the connection can't be opened b/c something about the connection string doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like you are missing the `;DATABASENAME=<dbname>` part in your connection string. See [this](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.03/en-US/66a4169b84b2466892e1af9781049836.html)

Comment: You need to check if the ODBC connection are correct.  From start button type ODBC Data Sources.

Comment: @Theo : This is ODBC and you use the ODBC Data Source to establish the connection.